# Opacity Highcharts pie chart IE8

Tags: highcharts

I want to add different opacity to each slice in a pie chart. It has to work in IE8. The most examples I find is using rgba, but since that does not work in IE8, the only way I can think of doing this is adding a css class to each slice. Is there any other way to do this, and if not, how can I add a css class to each slice?

Answer (score 0):

The [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mbgks8v2/1/show) seems to working fine.

IE8 8.0.6001.18702

```
data: [{
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 45.0,
            color: 'rgba(200,122,200,1)'
        }, {
            name: 'IE',
            y: 26.8,
            color: 'rgba(200,122,200,0.7)'
        }, {
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 12.8,
            color: 'rgba(200,122,200,0.4)'
 }]
```